# web2py serving zip file

Tags: zip, web2py, icalendar

I am trying to create and serve a zip file for user that contains ical files for different workers (each worker has his own ical file)

The problem is that i get the right number of iCal files in my zip but the last file has all the data from previous workers in it. (also the one before etc.)

this is the code I am using

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
cal = Calendar()
import zipfile, cStringIO
exported_chunks_zip = cStringIO.StringIO()
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(exported_chunks_zip, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED )

for i, rec in enumerate(grouped):
    worker =  rec['rw_worker_nick'].encode('cp1250')
    for rr in rec["allData"]:
        startDate = rr['rw_date']
        startTime = rr['rw_time_start']
        endTime = rr['rw_time_end']
        evtstart = datetime.datetime.combine(startDate,startTime)
        evtend = datetime.datetime.combine(startDate,endTime)
        event = Event()

        event.add('summary', rec['rw_worker_nick'])
        event.add('dtstart', evtstart)
        event.add('dtend', evtend)
        cal.add_component(event)
        text = cal.to_ical()
    zipf.writestr(worker +'.ics', text)
    text = ''
```

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create only a single `Calendar` object outside of the `for` loop and then keep appending events to it. You should instead create a new `Calendar` object for each worker within the `for` loop:

```
for i, rec in enumerate(grouped):
    cal = Calendar()
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can one download this zipped file via the browser? I've raised this question with details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804747/web2py-downloading-zip-file-created-by-cstringio-text-strings-in-controller